# How to hide some fields if user not logged in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to hide some fileds from not logged users. For example I have model account with fields:

name,
surname,
address,
tel,

and I want to hide address and tel fields if user is not logged in. I found some examples, but it hide whole model, not just a part I need.

Comment: Is this in the admin, in a view, do you have a modelform? Can you add this code to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in in templates by using built-in conditional tags:

```
{% comment %} Visible to everyone {% endcomment %}

{{ object.name }} {{ object.surname }} 

{% if request.user.is_authenticated %} 
{% comment %} Visible to logged in users only {% endcomment %}

    {{ object.address }}
    {{ object.tel }}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: You probably meant this:  {# some text #} for comments.